# Freeform page break count

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to get a page count for a Freeform composer form by counting the page breaks (or by some other method)?

Right now I'm just using the page_marker and pulling in the last url segment {last_segment}, which isn't ideal because I have no way of getting the total count (like - Step {count} of {total_count}).

I'm wondering if there's a native/better method out there?

```
    {exp:freeform:composer form_name="some_form_name" multipage="yes" page_marker="step/" inline_errors="yes"}

<div class="ff_composer">
{composer:page}

    {composer:rows}
            <div class="line">
        {composer:columns}
                <div class="unit size1of{composer:column_total}">

            {composer:fields}

                        <label class="field_label" for="freeform_{composer:field_name}">
                            {composer:field_label}{if composer:field_required}<span class="required_item">*</span>{/if}
                            {if freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}<span class="error">{freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}</span>{/if}
                        </label>                                                        

                    {composer:field_output}


            {/composer:fields}
                </div>
        {/composer:columns}
            </div>
    {/composer:rows}

{/composer:page}
</div>
```

{/exp:freeform:composer}

Answer (score 1):

Freeform:Form variables work in Composer templates, they are just parsed after all {composer: based variables are finished parsing as composer first parses everything that belongs to it, then pases the template to Freeform:Form for its parsing.

Thus if you are trying to get page totals just to display, you can use {freeform:form_page_total}

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_form_page_total